# ksmserver-logout-greeter crash after switching from Intel to NVidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kde

I'm new to Linux and I must say that this OS is blazing fast compared to my old Windows 10 installation. So I switched completely to Kumbuntu with KDE Plasma 5.8.4.

Now I have a small problem: By default Kumbuntu uses the intel Ivy Bridge GPU but if I switch to the Nvidia GPU I get a ksmserver-logout-greeter crash when I try to logout.

Only solution is to press the power button and make a "hard" restart. Then Kubuntu uses the Nvidia proprietary drivers (375.26).

Now my question:

Is this a bug with KDE Plasma or is there a more elegant solution than pressing the Power Button available?

Comment: Facing the same issue on openSUSE, I use `sudo shutdown -r 0`